# There is too much space in a div?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

So I am looking for the reason why a div in-particular has so much space at the bottom in my local preview, but in jsfiddle it does not.

In the JSFiddle it's the bottom div that's purple, but this is how it shows up in my local copy: http://prntscr.com/ingfwa

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eaLpf4f5/2/

Either that or the extra whitespace in the JSFiddle is the extra space in my local copy just colored purple? I've tried inspecting the code and it seems like it might be something with the last col-md-2 but that's a column, not a row, so I'm not sure. Also tried removing it to no effect.

I am aware the toolbar is broken right now as well, not focusing on that at the moment. Also I am aware the CSS is out of whack in terms of order of classes and ids in the HTML and CSS.

```css
#div3{
background-color: purple;
}

.formdiv{
  float:left;
  position: relative; 
  top: -25em;
  height: 25em;
}

.p6{
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
}

.bar5{
  border: 3px gray solid;
  width: 65%;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 10em;
}

#lt3{
  font-size: 2.9em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2.2em;
  top: -0.5em;
  color:white;
  font-family: Acme, sans-serif;
}

#lt4{
  font-size: 2.9em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15.5em;
  top: -2.2em;
  color:white;
  font-family: Acme, sans-serif;
}

.contacttextdiv{
  width: 10em;
  position: relative;
  left: 30em;
  top: -5em;
  font-size:  1.3em;
}

input, textarea { 
padding: 9px; 
border: solid 1px #E5E5E5; 
outline: 0; 
font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
width: 200px; 
background: #FFFFFF; 
} 
 
textarea 
{ 
width: 400px; 
max-width: 400px; 
height: 150px; 
line-height: 150%; 
} 
 
input:hover, textarea:hover, 
input:focus, textarea:focus { 
border-color: #C9C9C9; 
} 
 
.form label { 
margin-left: 10px; 
color: #999999; 
} 
 
.submit input { 
width: auto; 
padding: 9px 15px; 
background: #617798; 
border: 0; 
font-size: 14px; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
}

input, textarea { 
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
}

input, textarea { 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE), #FFFFFF 25px); 
}

input:hover, textarea:hover, 
input:focus, textarea:focus { 
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px; 
}

.submit input { 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
</head>


<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="navbar">
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#news">News</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">Test</div>
            <div class="col-md-8" id="div1">
              <div>
                <p id="p1"><strong>Front-end developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</strong></p> 
                <p id="p2"><div class="bar"></div>
                <p id="lt1"><strong>&lt;/&gt;</strong></p>
                  <p class="p2"><strong> Web Developer - User Experience Designer</strong></p>
                <img src="LOGO.jpg" class="pic1"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">Test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8" id="div2">
              <p class="p4"><strong>Portfolio</strong></p>
              <div class="bar2"></div>
              <div class="bar3"></div>
                <p id="lt2"><strong>&lt;/&gt;</strong></p>
                <img src="fakesample1.jpg" class="pic2"/>
                <img src="fakesample2.jpg" class="pic3"/>
                <img src="fakesample3.jpg" class="pic4"/>
                <img src="fakesample4.jpg" class="pic5"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                
            <div class="col-md-8" id="div3">
                <p class="p6"><strong>Contact Me</strong></p>
                <p id="p2"><div class="bar5"></div>
                    <p id="lt3"><strong>&lt;/&gt;</strong></p>
                    <p id="lt4"><strong>&lt;/&gt;</strong></p>
                    <div class="contacttextdiv">
                        <p class="contacttext"><strong>Contact me here! If you want me to do web design work, walk your dog, pet your cat, water your plants, or just have a chat! This is the place to do it! No spam please, thanks.</p></strong>
                    </div>
              <div class="formdiv">
                 
                    <form class="form"> 
   
                    <p class="name"> 
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
                        <label for="name">Name</label> 
                    </p> 
                   
                    <p class="email"> 
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label> 
                    </p> 
                   
                    <p class="web"> 
                        <input type="text" name="web" id="web" /> 
                        <label for="web">Website</label> 
                    </p> 
                   
                    <p class="text"> 
                        <textarea name="text"></textarea> 
                    </p> 
                   
                    <p class="submit"> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" /> 
                    </p> 
                   
                </form>                
                

            </div>

        
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="bottombar1">About This Page</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12"></div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<div class="col-md-8" id="div3">` element has a `.row` element immediately after it - that should be wrapped in a column (or a .container element, if on top level), otherwise the grid won’t work.

Comment: Atleast give a properly intended code, so one can understand your problem.

Comment: Hm, I'm seeing a col-md-2 immediately after the entire element if that's what you're referring to, otherwise I don't see it, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change height

```
.formdiv {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -25em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eaLpf4f5/10/

Comment: Jeezus. I could have sworn I tested that earlier when I was inspecting the elements on the page, huh. Thanks.